# Integral sign using eulervm and newpx

Tags: math-operators, eulervm

I've tried to load `eulervm` alongside `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`, and this has worked fine until I attempted to construct an integral using `\int`. The integral sign simply doesn't appear:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} 
    \usepackage{eulervm}

    \begin{document} 
    \[\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\] 
    \end{document}
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Funny interaction: I'm not sure what is the reason, but why are you loading `newpxmath` at all if you want to use `eulervm`? Removing it works just fine...

Comment: @campa I loaded `newpxmath` because `\operatorname` wouldn't work without it.

Comment: `\operatorname` is defined by `amsmath`, which is loaded by default by `newpxmath`. But you can load it separately.

Answer (score 3):

One can redeclare the integral operator, `\intop`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} 
\usepackage{eulervm}
\DeclareMathSymbol\intop \mathop {largesymbols}{"52}
\begin{document} 
\[\int_a^b f(x)\, dx  \quad\textstyle\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one could save a version of `\intop` before loading `newpxmath` and then restore it afterwards:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svintop\intop
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} 
\let\intop\svintop
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document} 
\[\int_a^b f(x)\, dx  \quad\textstyle\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\] 
\end{document}
```

As a third way, one could just load the `euler` package, instead of `eulervm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} 
\usepackage{euler}
\begin{document} 
\[\int_a^b f(x)\, dx  \quad\textstyle\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\] 
\end{document}
```

---

**DISCUSSION**

All this happens for two reasons: because `eulervm` does not explicitly declare `\intop` and also because `newpxmath` redefines `\intop` (by default) with

```
\let\intop=\intslop
```

where

```
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\intslop}                {\mathop}{largesymbols}{"AF}
```

This "AF is a different glyph slot than the "52 used by `eulervm`.  And `\intop` is an integral part of `\int`, as defined in `newpxmath` as

```
\def\int{\DOTSI\intop\ilimits@}
```

This MWE shows the discussion explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\sbox0{DEFAULT: \meaning\intop}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} 
\sbox2{NEWPXMATH: \meaning\intop}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\sbox4{EULER DOES NOT FIX: \meaning\intop}
\DeclareMathSymbol\intop \mathop {largesymbols}{"52}
\sbox6{REDECLARED: \meaning\intop}
\begin{document} 
\[\int_a^b f(x)\, dx  \quad\textstyle\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\] 

\box0

\box2

\box4

\box6
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**POSTSCRIPT**

The package `euler` does not suffer the same problem because it explicitly declares the `\intop` symbol to slot "52.